# Appium on MacOS doesn't recognize android device on VMware

Tags: android, macos, appium, vmware

I am wroking on a MAC OS X (10.11) as Vmware guest. Connected my Samsung Galaxy S5 using a USB cable. Using backup apps, i am able to see the device. But using Appium \ iTunes, not. I have set all the required fields (app path, package name, launchable activity, along with device name, and pointed the android sdk path).

Answer (score 0):

Answering in case someone else encountered this problem: What i had to do is start the Appium server and load the Appium Inspector. Only then the application was loaded on the Android device and i was able to get elements from the device.

But it is stil weird to me, that i must open the Inspector, in order for the application to be launched. As it doesn't seem logically to do so when executing a test.